# XSLTransform to MemoryStream

Tags: c#, xslt

Can one write the results of a XSLTransform.Transform to a memorystream instead of a XMLTextWriter object?

I need to be able to send the results of my transform over the wire to a webbrowser, so writing it to a file on disk on the server is no good.

Tony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other option is to use the newer [XslCompiledTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx), which has an overload to output to a Stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily hook an XmlTextWriter up to a StringWriter, and then send the resulting string to the browser:

```
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter);

// write your transform to xmlTextWriter...

xmlTextWriter.Flush();
xmlTextWriter.Close();
stringWriter.Flush();

string result = stringWriter.ToString();
```